# The contents of two jQuery event handlers, which should be functionally equivalent, exhibit different behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two identical document fragment objects, and I attach a separate event listener to each using jQuery, [as you can see in my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/omgtoblerone/7j9bex15/)

The contents of the two event listeners *should* be functionally equivalent, but for some reason only the first event listener acts as expected.

Here is my function for creating document fragments:

```
function createDocFrag(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}
```

That function accepts an HTML string as its argument - here is the markup for said Document Fragments:

```
<div class='product current'>
    <div class='collapsed'>
        <p class='name'></p>
        <p class='price'><span></span></p>
        <div class='info'><p>i</p></div>
    </div>\
    <div class='expanded'>
        <ul>
            <li class='base'><span> GHz Base</span></li>
            <li class='turbo'><span> GHz Turbo</span></li>
            <li class='cores'><span> Cores</span></li>
            <li class='threads'><span> Threads</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here are the two event listeners:

```
$(fragment1).find(".info").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parents(".product").toggleClass("expand");
});

$(fragment2).find(".info").on("click", function(){
    $(fragment2).find(".product").toggleClass("expand");
});
```

Would love to know what's causing this behavior (or lack thereof), so any clarity on the subject would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: By doing $(fragment2) the second time, you are re-creating an object using fragment2.

Comment: @Lauromine: Actually they were proper DOM fragments, not strings. I made the same mistake initially as the code is only in the fiddle. The problem is that DOM fragments appear to vanish as separate fragments once appended to the DOM. Quite odd really.

Comment: For the most intriguing puzzle I have had lately, +1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget my first attempt. You really did throw me with the use of the function creating DOM fragments.

The reason it does not work is that the fragments are undefined after they have been appended to the `body` element. The only reason the first one works is that it uses DOM navigation relative to the clicked element. Add this inside the first click handler to check:

```
alert($(fragment1).html());   // Undefined!!!
```

### Alternatives:

I would suggest doing things in a more "jQuery" way and use templates in the page. This has the advantage of it being easier to maintain HTML in HTML.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7j9bex15/2/

Place your template in a dummy script block with an unknown type so it is ignored by the browser. I use `text/template`:

```
<script id="fragment" type="text/template">
    <div class='product current'>
        <div class='collapsed'>
            <p class='name'></p>
            <p class='price'><span></span></p>
            <div class='info'><p>i</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class='expanded'>
            <ul>
                <li class='base'><span> GHz Base</span></li>
                <li class='turbo'><span> GHz Turbo</span></li>
                <li class='cores'><span> Cores</span></li>
                <li class='threads'><span> Threads</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Refer to the html by the id of the block:

```
var fragment = $('#fragment').html();
```

And use delegated event handlers, attached to a non-changing ancestor element to catch the click events on dynamically added content:

```
$(document).on('click', '.info', function(){
});
```

Use `closest` (not `parents`) to find the first closest matching ancestor, then `toggleClass` as before:

```
$(this).closest(".product").toggleClass("expand");
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow - how is the second part creating a second fragment? Surely, since I reference the `fragment2` variable, it should refer to the same element?

Comment: Actually your code in the JSFiddle is completely different to what I was expecting... Give me a few minutes to work through this :)

Comment: Threw you a curveball with that function eh? Haha! Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I'd love for you to elaborate on templated html elements, because if you have a better solution then I'd love to see it...my solution seemed **really messy**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88016/discussion-between-jonathan-brooks-and-trueblueaussie).